# Python - SkLearn Imputer usage

Tags: python, scikit-learn, imputation

I have the following question: I have a pandas dataframe, in which missing values are marked by the string `na`. I want to run an Imputer on it to replace the missing values with the mean in the column. According to the sklearn documentation, the parameter `missing_values` should help me with this:

> missing_values : integer or “NaN”, optional (default=”NaN”) The
>   placeholder for the missing values. All occurrences of missing_values
>   will be imputed. For missing values encoded as np.nan, use the string
>   value “NaN”.

In my understanding, this means, that if I write

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename)
imp = Imputer(missing_values='na')
imp.fit_transform(df)
```

that would mean that the imputer replaces anything in the dataframe with the `na` value with the mean of the column. However, instead, I get an error:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: na
```

What am I misinterpreting? Is this not how the imputer should work? How can I replace the `na` strings with the mean, then? Should I just use a lambda for it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you say you want to replace these `'na'` by a the mean of the column, I'm guessing the non-missing values are indeed floats. The problem is that pandas does not recognize the string `'na'` as a missing value, and so reads the column with dtype `object` instead of some flavor of `float`.

Case in point, consider the following `.csv` file:

```
 test.csv

 col1,col2
 1.0,1.0
 2.0,2.0
 3.0,3.0
 na,4.0
 5.0,5.0
```

With the naive import `df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')`, `df.dtypes` tells us that `col1` is of dtype `object` and `col2` is of dtype `float64`. But how do you take the mean of a bunch of objects?

The solution is to tell `pd.read_csv()` to interpret the string `'na'` as a missing value:

```
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', na_values='na')
```

The resulting dataframe has both columns of dtype `float64`, and you can now use your imputer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the error I was receiving

> IndexError: in the future, 0-d boolean arrays will be interpreted as a valid boolean index

In my case I had issue with "median" strategy, changing it to mean or most_frequent worked.

Answer (score 0):

first import   `pandas`   then read the  `your_file_name.csv`  . And   `iloc`  is defined pandas.DataFrame.iloc and is purley integer based indexing for location by position . Here format is  `iloc[for row index , for column index]` where a,b,c,d are integers ab,c ,d can also be empty

```
import pandas as pd
dataSet = pd.read_csv('your_file_name.csv')
X = dataSet.iloc[ a:b , c:d].values
```

if you use without .values then you will not be able to make it used in imputer for transformation 
here after importing   `Imputer`  define your `Imputer`  parameters  `missing_values` =
"missing values in data that you want to replace " ,`strategy ="mean"` (two more 
strategies are there which it follows i.e. median and most frequently occured in 
your dataSet but default is mean . Then set axis = (0 for column and 1 for row ) , other are copy and verbose  ) you can read more about it  on

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer
i = Imputer(missing_values="NaN", strategy="mean", axis=0)
```

fit the data into your defined way of Imputer and then transform it using transform method . this will return array of datatype = object

```
i  = i.fit(X[a:b, c:d])
X[a:b, c:d ] = i.transform(X[a:b,c:d])
```

Remember here your selected columns show contain only float or integer type values otherwise this may show error can't convert string to float

Answer (score 0):

There are several things you need to pay attention here.

Make sure you are not imputing on type "object" or categorial variables, you can have a look on your data like this:

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename)

print(df.info(null_counts=True))
```

The last colunm should be the type

Let's see an example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : [1, 2, 2, 2, 'NaN', 3, 4, 5, 6], 'B' : [3, 3, 'NaN', 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3]})
```

output:

```
df.head()


    A   B
---------
0   1   3
1   2   3
2   2   NaN
3   2   3
4   NaN 3
```

Now let's have a look on the types

```
df.info(null_counts=True)

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 9 entries, 0 to 8
Data columns (total 2 columns):
0    9 non-null float64
1    9 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(2)
memory usage: 224.0 bytes
```

Now imputing:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer
imputer = Imputer(missing_values='NaN', strategy='most_frequent', axis=0)
df_imputed = pd.DataFrame(imputer.fit_transform(df))
df_imputed.head()


    0   1
-----------
0   1.0 3.0
1   2.0 3.0
2   2.0 3.0
3   2.0 3.0
4   2.0 3.0
```

Now this is all good and well but cannot be done on categorial (type Object / String)

One way to handle it, is to change the Categorical features to numeric, something like this:

```
df_with_cat = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['ios', 'android', 'web', 'NaN'], 'B' : [4, 4, 'NaN', 2]})
df_with_cat.head()


      A     B
-------------
0   ios     4
1   android 4
2   web     NaN
3   NaN     2
```

And info

```
df_with_cat.info(null_counts=True)

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 4 entries, 0 to 3
Data columns (total 2 columns):
A    4 non-null object
B    4 non-null object
dtypes: object(2)
memory usage: 144.0+ bytes
```

We know for sure that B is numerical so, let's do this:

```
df_with_cat['B'] = df_with_cat['B'].astype(np.float)
df_with_cat.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 4 entries, 0 to 3
Data columns (total 2 columns):
A    4 non-null object
B    3 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(1), object(1)
memory usage: 144.0+ bytes
```

If we would use the very same imputer from above we'd get an error (you can try it out)

Now let's transform the 'A' categories to numbers:

```
CATEGORICAL_FEATURES = [
    'A', 
]
data_dum = pd.get_dummies(df_with_cat, columns=['A'], drop_first=True)
data_dum.head()

    B   A_android   A_ios   A_web
---------------------------------
0   4       0         1       0
1   4       1         0       0
2   NaN     0         0       1
3   2       0         0       0
```

Now we can run the very same Imputer from above on our data frame